# SSIS - How to retrieve all the elements of ROOT using XML Task

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

So, I have an XML file that contains an order and for which I am using a `Data Flow Task` in order to extract the information and insert them into some tables in `MSSQL`. So far, so good. However, there are some information that I cannot reach to using this method and I need to use an `XML Task` for this:

[image: XML Task]

But, I would like to extract several information, not just one field. How can I achieve this and use it further to insert them into a table? My `XML` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <UBLVersionID>2.1</UBLVersionID>
    <CustomizationID>ver2.0</CustomizationID>
    <ProfileID>RO11588780_RO13965909</ProfileID>
    <ID>00680733</ID>
    <CopyIndicator>true</CopyIndicator>
    <UUID>DX01_144_20181119_01006030</UUID>
    <IssueDate>2018-11-19</IssueDate>
    <OrderTypeCode>220</OrderTypeCode>
    <Note>STOCAJ</Note>
    <AccountingCostCode>32</AccountingCostCode>
    <LineCountNumeric>16</LineCountNumeric>
    <RequestedDeliveryPeriod>
        <StartDate>2018-11-23</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-11-23</EndDate>
        <Description/>
    </RequestedDeliveryPeriod>
    <BuyerCustomerParty>
        <ID>233</ID>
        <Price CurrencyID="RON">
            <Amount>40.85</Amount>
        </Price>
        <Quantity UnitCode="PCE">
            <Amount>2</Amount>
        </Quantity>
        <Item>
            <Description>HARRY POTTER 7</Description>
            <PackQuantity>1</PackQuantity>
            <PackSizeNumeric>2</PackSizeNumeric>
            <BuyersItemIdentification>32527676</BuyersItemIdentification>
            <StandardItemIdentification>9786067884159</StandardItemIdentification>
        </Item>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
        <ID>234</ID>
        <Price CurrencyID="RON">
            <Amount>20.61</Amount>
        </Price>
        <Quantity UnitCode="PCE">
            <Amount>2</Amount>
        </Quantity>
        <Item>
            <Description>ARCUL DE ARAMA</Description>
            <PackQuantity>1</PackQuantity>
            <PackSizeNumeric>2</PackSizeNumeric>
            <BuyersItemIdentification>32527677</BuyersItemIdentification>
            <StandardItemIdentification>9786068811574</StandardItemIdentification>
        </Item>
    </OrderLine>
</Order>
```

Comment: Honestly, I find the xml reader in SSIS awful. From personal experience I find it far easier to import the raw xml into SQL Server and then using XQUERY to do the work.

Comment: How can I do this? Is going to always another file with another name so basically I need to take all the files from a specific folder with the `.xml` extension.

Comment: If you need to do an operation for each object, you need to  use an (appropriately named) For Each Loop Container; which can loop on files in a directory (and recurse if needed).

Comment: I know this with `For Each Loop`. But I also need to extract some info from the root element.

Comment: Yes, see my original comment.

Comment: So, can I combine both the XQUERY with For Each Loop in SSIS?

Comment: Use the For Each Loop Container to insert the raw xml into SQL Server, and then use XQUERY on the data in SQL Server (after you've inserted all the raw xml data, as that makes more sense). At least, that's what I would do.

Comment: Could you point me to an example? Don't really know how to do this from a variable. Thanks

Comment: Not from home; I don't use Windows there and SSDT is unsupported (still) on Linux. What part are you struggling with? Making a text source use an expression as the filepath? If so, select your Text File Source, hit F4, go to expressions in the properties pane, and the rest *should* be self explanatory. If you want to include the filename in your Dataflow, you can use a Computed Column Transformation and simply create a column with the value of your variable.

Comment: I can't explain how to get the values you want from your XML, as Idon't know what data you want (you've simply stated you want data from the root node).

Answer (score 0):

First of all i changed your xml file to (Sql server was complaining about the tags..):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <UBLVersionID>2.1</UBLVersionID>
    <CustomizationID>ver2.0</CustomizationID>
    <ProfileID>RO11588780_RO13965909</ProfileID>
    <ID>00680733</ID>
    <CopyIndicator>true</CopyIndicator>
    <UUID>DX01_144_20181119_01006030</UUID>
    <IssueDate>2018-11-19</IssueDate>
    <OrderTypeCode>220</OrderTypeCode>
    <Note>STOCAJ</Note>
    <AccountingCostCode>32</AccountingCostCode>
    <LineCountNumeric>16</LineCountNumeric>
    <RequestedDeliveryPeriod>
        <StartDate>2018-11-23</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-11-23</EndDate>
        <Description></Description>
    </RequestedDeliveryPeriod>
    <BuyerCustomerParty>
        <ID>233</ID>
        <Price CurrencyID="RON">
            <Amount>40.85</Amount>
        </Price>
        <Quantity UnitCode="PCE">
            <Amount>2</Amount>
        </Quantity>
        <Item>
            <Description>HARRY POTTER 7</Description>
            <PackQuantity>1</PackQuantity>
            <PackSizeNumeric>2</PackSizeNumeric>
            <BuyersItemIdentification>32527676</BuyersItemIdentification>
            <StandardItemIdentification>9786067884159</StandardItemIdentification>
        </Item>
    <OrderLine>
    </OrderLine>
        <ID>234</ID>
        <Price CurrencyID="RON">
            <Amount>20.61</Amount>
        </Price>
        <Quantity UnitCode="PCE">
            <Amount>2</Amount>
        </Quantity>
        <Item>
            <Description>ARCUL DE ARAMA</Description>
            <PackQuantity>1</PackQuantity>
            <PackSizeNumeric>2</PackSizeNumeric>
            <BuyersItemIdentification>32527677</BuyersItemIdentification>
            <StandardItemIdentification>9786068811574</StandardItemIdentification>
        </Item>
    <OrderLine>
    </OrderLine>
</BuyerCustomerParty>
</Order>
```

After doing that , you can access your data as :

```
 Declare @fileData  XML 
             Select @fileData=BulkColumn from OpenRowSet(Bulk'PathtoXML\XMLFileName.xml',Single_blob) x;


 select 
                x.xData.value('ID[1]','int'),
                x.xData.value('Price[1]','float'),
                x.xData.value('Quantity[1]','int')
             from @fileData.nodes('/Order/BuyerCustomerParty') 
             x(xData);
```

This for the /Order/BuyerCustomerParty node.. You can declare                    /Order/BuyerCustomerParty/Item as node and call x.xData.value('Description[1]','varChar(max)') for the Item description and so goes on...
Your select can be easily inserted in a temporary table , from which you can manage yoyr xml data.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice spot on the `OrderLine` node that is ended before one is opened. If that, however, is how the OP's data looks then that does mean they need to fix (all of) their XML so that it's valid.

Comment: Well, maybe I missed to copy also the `OrderLine` enging tag. Before I need to do all this, I have to import the raw xml data into a table, using a For Each Loop.

Comment: It has multiple errors on tags , not just this. </BuyerCustomerParty> is missing also , for example. I think i inserted 3-4  tags.. You can use also , a header table and a detail one (for the items) and insert data with the INSERT...SELECT statements, without using Loop. We dont know your exact purpose , so we speak  hypothetically.

Comment: Please have in mind that I just mistype, that's all.